# How download file in different folder from different URLs by asyncTask?

Tags: java, android

I have an app that download multiply files from a two URLs to download folder by asyncTask . It works perfectly but I want download file in a different folder. for example, file 1 download in App folder and file 2 download in download folder.. how can do like this?

```
 Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
 button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
       String url1 = "https://www.example.com";
                            new DownloadFont().execute(url1);
    }
 });


 Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
 button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
       String url2 = "https://www.example2url.com";
                            new DownloadFont().execute(url2);
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a Boolean as Parameter and define the path depending on the boolean.

```
@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Boolean saveToAppfolder, String... arg) {

    String PATH = "";
    if (saveToAppfolder) {
        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/AppFolder/";
    } else {
        //OTHER Folder
    }
}
```

or you can send the path within the String[]

```
@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... arg) {

    String PATH = arg[1];
}
```

Implement one of the examples above and do:

```
 Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
 button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View v) {
   String url1 = "https://www.example.com";
   new DownloadFile().execute(false, url1); // first example
   new DownloadFile().execute(url1, pathToDownloadTo); //second example
}
});


Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View v) {
   String url2 = "https://www.example2url.com";
   new DownloadFile().execute(false, url2); // first example
   new DownloadFile().execute(url2, pathToDownloadTo); //second example
}
});
```

Comment: Thank you , I know this but i mean i have two button for download not like this  new DownloadFile().execute(s1,s2); . how can define  like button 1 DownloadFile().execute(s1); and button 2 DownloadFile().execute(s2);

Comment: @J.dana3 If you want to have seperate download folders you need to give the method an aditional parameter like you see in my examples.

Comment: I guess you did not understand me :( .. see update in code :) .. how define file if get from button number 1 or 2

Comment: @J.dana3 you define the file with the path you give the file see my updated code

Comment: Glad I could help :)